# How to colorize a part of table

Tags: c#, linq

I got this code which shows multiplication table, and I should make a diagonal of colored squares, but surely I do not know how. Could anyone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Task1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void tab(byte b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's {0} x {0}\n", b);
            // Rows
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                // Columns
                for (int j = 1; j <= b; j++)
                Console.Write("{0}\t", j * i);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            tab(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's truly `b x b` then your rows loop should be `<= b` not 10.

On the matter at hand, your diagional occurs when `i == j`, so that would be your conditional on which you need to colorize.

If you need help colorizing, use the `Console.BackgroundColor` member to set that. Don't forget to change it back when you're done with a colored box.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks! Now the only question for me is how to close this topic.

Comment: Why would you want to close it? If it wasn't useful, I would have closed it instead of answering it. =)